# Create a DLL from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linker, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have created a DLL in MATLAB which provides me an interface to my .m functions.

Now I would like to use it with the MCR Runtime Library. (MCR = Matlab Compiler Runtime).

I am calling this DLL from within a C routine which eventually gets compiled with GCC (MinGW) into a wrapper DLL.

Now my function gets put into two forms:

```
extern LIB_XYZ_C_API 
bool MW_CALL_CONV mlxGet_path(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);
extern LIB_XYZ_C_API bool MW_CALL_CONV mlfGet_path(int nargout, mxArray** p);
```

From these I choose the latter one as the former on seems to be kind of "old-style/legacy".

I call it this way:

```
char get_path(LStrHandle path)
{
    char mret = init_XYZ(); // here I call mclmcrInitialize(), mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0) etc.
    if (mret) return mret;
    mret = 2;
    // here the relevant part begins
    mxArray * mxpath = NULL; // set it to NULL and let the callee allocate it
    bool bret = mlfGet_path(1, &mxpath);
    // now I convert the mxpath to a string
    // What do I do with the mxpath afterwards?
    // I try to free it with
    mxDestroyArray(mxpath);
    return mret;
}
```

**And here the trouble begins**: `mxDestroyArray()` cannot be found in the linking process:

```
undefined reference to `mxDestroyArray'
```

If I manually add `-llibmx` to the build process, the build runs, but then `libmx.dll` cannot be found, as the MCR only puts `$MCR\runtime\win32` into the path, but not `$MCR\bin\win32` where the `libmx.dll` lives.

What can I do?

Do I have to choose a different "destroy" function when I use a self-compiled DLL?

Or do I have to fool around with the path? (I don't hope so...)

Besides, there are other functions which are missing, but I think this would be resolved in the same way:

```
mxGetNumberOfElements
mxIsDouble
mxGetPr
mxGetM
mxGetN
mxGetData
mxIsChar
mxIsCell
mxDestroyArray
mxGetCell_730
mxSetCell_730
mxGetString_730
mxCalcSingleSubscript_730
mxGetNumberOfDimensions_730
mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730
mxCreateNumericMatrix_730
mxCreateCellMatrix_730
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is the solution, but the recent versions of Matlab allow you to add files to the project (before compilation) that are not linked automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it makes a big difference if the MCR is used or an installed MATLAB installation.

1. Use `-lmclmcrrt` instead of `-lmx` and use the correct library path for the linker.
2. Use the correct `#include` files in every file used in the compilation. Especially, don't inter-mix `#include "matrix.h"` and the header file created together with the MATLAB DLL.